# Bin expression by count

Tags: spotfire

I need Spotfire to bin the count of a field. For example if I have a field named COST_CENTER, I need to show 3 bins as the X axis on a chart.

- Bin 1: COST_CENTERs that shows up once in the data table go in here
- Bin 2: COST_CENTERs that show up 2-3 times
- Bin 3: COST_CENTERs that show up 4+ times

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the image below you can see the data and the chart.
I created two calculated columns.
One is called Count([Job]) but its formula is: Count([JOB]) OVER ([JOB]).

This first column returns in each row the number of occurences of a particular job name within the dataset. 
That would be your COST_CENTER.

Then I defined/inserted a binned column with the formula of: BinBySpecificLimits([Count([JOB]])],10,30,100)

This Binned column is shown on the chart. So basically it collects in first bin all the Jobs
that shows up between 10 and 30 times and all the jobs that shows between 30 and 100 times in the second bin.

Last third bin with jobs showing up more than 100 times is empty.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jacek. Great answer. I didn't think of doing the Count([JOB]) OVER ([JOB]) as a calculated column.